# how to install exchange and active directory on seperate machines

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

I am trying to build a lab environment, that replicates a production one. I need to know how
to make things work together after installing active directory on a seperate machine probably a 2012 server and exchange 2010 on a different machine. I understand that the Exchange server should be a member of the domain, but how does it authenticate against D.C for account creation, authentication and other things. does it need to be a member server..?

Also, i'm thinking about having another dedicated machine as a terminal server hosting office 
applications. How to make use of active directory authentication for terminal server.

what does that mean by split permissions versus shared permissions in exchange 2010.and activ dir.?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

> I understand that the Exchange server should be a member of the domain, but how does it authenticate against D.C for account creation, authentication and other things. does it need to be a member server..?

Yes. That's what a member server is. A server that is joined to the domain.

> Also, i'm thinking about having another dedicated machine as a terminal server hosting office applications. How to make use of active directory authentication for terminal server.

The same way you would for any server. Join it to the domain.

> Also, i'm thinking about having another dedicated machine as a terminal server hosting office applications. How to make use of active directory authentication for terminal server.

Exchange and Active Directory are both well documented. Please read the thorough and complete documentation before proceeding. The largest part of a (good) sysadmin's job is reading and understanding documentation. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638106(v=exchg.141).aspx